# Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-dynamodb

I have a project that was created on Windows. After moving to macOS and trying to install and run it, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/beygel/ITECH/Projects/Moovz-Server/stats/node_modules/dynamodb/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/beygel/ITECH/Projects/Moovz-Server/stats/node_modules/dynamodb/node_modules/bunyan/lib/bunyan.js:34:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "simple-xmpp": "^1.3.0",
    "dynamodb": "^1.1.2",
    "html2plaintext": "^2.1.2",
    "memcache-plus": "0.2.18",
    "memjs": "^1.2.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.1",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "socket.io-client": "0.9.16"
  }
```

System info:

- node: v11.6.0
- npm: 6.8.0
- mbp2018: macOS Mojave version 10.14.3

Comment: What have you tried to do to fix the problem? I'm assuming you already did a `npm install` ?

Comment: I tried installing packages, installing dtrace-provider, bunyan

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Any further findings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got rid of this error by running `rm -rf node_modules` and then running `npm i --no-optional` with `dtrace-provider` in my dependencies. It was at version `0.8.7`.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved when I ran `npm rebuild dtrace-provider`